# Why does "[] == False" evaluate to False when "if not []" succeeds?

Tags: python

I'm asking this because I know that the pythonic way to check whether a list is empty or not is the following:

```
my_list = []
if not my_list:
    print "computer says no"
else:
    # my_list isn't empty
    print "computer says yes"
```

will print `computer says no`, etc. So this leads me to identify `[]` with `False` truth-values; however, if I try to compare [] and False "directly", I obtain the following:

```
>>> my_list == False
False
>>> my_list is False
False
>>> [] == False
False
```

etc...

What's going on here? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: This is great design, as it also gets programmers to not use the `if variable == True:` clause.  It should either be `if variable is True:` (It's exactly True, not anything else  -- Not the best way to do things in most cases), or `if variable` (it's truth-y).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `if` statement evaluates everything in a Boolean context, it is like there is an implicit call to the [`bool()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bool) built-in function.

Here is how you would actually check how things will be evaluated by an `if` statement:

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([]) == False
True
```

See the documentation on [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), empty lists are *considered false*, but this doesn't mean they are equivalent to `False`.

[PEP 285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) also has some excellent information on why it was implemented this way, see the very last bullet in the *Resolved Issues* section for the part that deals with `x == True` and `x == False` specifically.

The most convincing aspect to me is that `==` is generally transitive, so `a == b` and `b == c` implies `a == c`.  So if it were the way you expected and `[] == False` were true and `'' == False` were true, one might assume that `[] == ''` should be true (even though it obviously should not be in a language without implicit type conversion).

Comment: "Even though it obviously should not be," ***Javascript***.

Answer (score 14):

Empty containers are "falsy," that is, they evaluate to `False` *in a Boolean context*. That doesn't mean they are literally equal to the constant `False`.

In other words, the following is `True`:

```
bool([]) == False
```

The truth value of an object is determined by its `__nonzero__()` or its `__len__()` method. (In Python 3, `__nonzero__()` has been renamed to `__bool__()`.) Containers have a `__len__()` method, so they are truthy when they have anything in them and falsy when they are empty.

If empty containers were literally equal to `False`, by the way, then any empty container would be equal to any other empty container: for example, `{} == ""` would be `True`. And that just wouldn't make any sense at all!

However, just to blow your mind, the following is `True`:

```
False == 0
```

This is because Booleans are a subclass of integers in Python, and `False` is basically just a zero that gets printed a little differently.

Answer (score 7):

Built-in types in Python have a truth value which allows you to test them for truthfulness. See *[Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)*.

This is different than saying `object == False` which is doing an actual value test (equality test). It is using the objects `__eq__()` method to determine if their values are equal.

Comment: I find this the most useful answer, personally. Truthyness is an interesting concept, and can lead to some unintuitive consequences. Take JavaScript and it's bottom values as an example.

Comment: @dwerner: Yea I agree. I just try and think about it as "if this object has content" when I say `if object:`

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the not operator is causing your list to be converted to a boolean.  Try this:

```
>>> not []
True

>>> not [1]
False
```

"is" and "==" don't do that conversion.

Comment: This is a really good point that the `not` operator is converting to a Boolean, but you have it backwards.  `(not []) == True` and `(not [1]) == False`.