# Empty list is equal to None or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ironpython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does “[] == False” evaluate to False when “if not []” succeeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440792/why-does-false-evaluate-to-false-when-if-not-succeeds)

I am new to python  as per ternary operator of python

```
>>> 'true' if True else 'false'  true
   true
```

i am expecting for below code output as [] because [] not equal to None

```
>>> a=[]
>>> a==None
False
>>> a if a else None
None
```

pleas correct if i am wrong

Thanks
hema

Comment: See the documentation for [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Comment: Better answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The empty list, `[]`, is **not** equal to `None`.

However, it **can** evaluate to `False`--that is to say, its "truthiness" value is `False`.  (See the sources in the comments left on the OP.)

Because of this,

```py
>>> [] == False
False
>>> if []:
...     print "true!"
... else:
...     print "false!"
false!
```

Comment: The easiest way to put it is `[] != False` but `bool([]) == False`.

Comment: @Lattyware True, it's the most concise way, but I'd think a Python newbie might have trouble following though.

Comment: Oh, indeed, I'm not suggesting you remove your excellent explanation, just putting it another way.

Comment: Answer by @GarethLatty was what I was looking for. My function removes things from a list based on criteria and should return false overall if the list becomes empty. `return bool([])` is perfect for that.

Comment: @VISQL you still don't need `bool([])`, you can just return `[]`, since `[]` evaluates false-y.

Answer (score 3):

`None` is the sole instance of the `NoneType` and is usually used to signify absence of value. What happens in your example is that the empty list, taken in boolean context, evaluates to `False`, the condition fails, so the else branch gets executed. The interpreter does something along the lines of:

```
>>> a if a else None
    [] if [] else None
    [] if False else None
None
```

Here is another useful discussion regarding `None`: [not None test in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python)