# Python: logical expression is False, but if doesn't care

Tags: python, boolean-expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does “[] == False” evaluate to False when “if not []” succeeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440792/why-does-false-evaluate-to-false-when-if-not-succeeds)

How is this possible that logical test a==True produces False, but if a: works? Please see code below

```
>>> a = bin(0)
>>> if a:
    print a == True, 'HOWWWW???????'


False HOWWWW???????
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

Comment: Python has a short list of expressions which are evaluated to false in this documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `if` statement doesn't depend on whether the value is equal to true.  It depends on whether `bool(a)` is equal to True, which in this case it is.  Nonempty strings are considered true in a boolean context.  See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#booleans).

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems in python you can't test a string this way:

```
>>> a == False
False
>>> a == True
False
>>>
```

Comment: Why not? A string will never be equal to True or False, because neither True nor False is a string. At least it doesn't raise an exception!

Answer (score 0):

for a string `a` , `if a` is equivalent to `if len(a)!=0`