# javascript why Array() is true?

Tags: javascript

Following code will output 'true', that means Array() is true. In Python, list() is False, is this just because the language designer's preference?

```
    document.write("<p>Array() is " + (Array() ? "true" : "false") + "</p>");
```

Comment: Helpful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440792/why-does-false-evaluate-to-false-when-if-not-succeeds#answer-10440825

Comment: it looks like low understanding of JS Objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because javascript coerces the value of `Array()` into a boolean.  This is what's referred to as "truthiness", and in javascript, truthy values include any valid object.  `Array()` produces a valid object, and therefore evaluates as a true value in a boolean expression.

`Null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, and the empty string `""` evaluate as false.

Why?  Because the [ECMAScript spec](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.2) says so.

Comment: There are even languages where 0 evaluates as true (Lua).

Answer (score 0):

Array() is truthy. In other words, it has a value, and the value is not false, null or undefined. There are many lists of what is truthy and not out there on the web for javascript. Just as an example, a more 'standard'/'accepted' way of creating a new array is by using an array literal - []. If you put this in your console, you'll get "true" as well.

```
console.log(!!([]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Array() returns array here (though empty), try `(Array().length ? "true" : "false")`

Comment: Yes, but you're *still* doing an implicit type conversion here, because `Array().length` is an integer, not a boolean.

Comment: @kojiro what's implicit in `.length`?

Comment: The question is about implicit Boolean conversion, e.g. *Why is an empty array `false` in one language and `true` in another?* Your answer suggests that instead of one implicit Boolean conversion `Array() ? "true" : "false"` ⇒ `Boolean({}) ? "true" : "false"`, OP should use a *different* implicit Boolean conversion `Array().length ? "true" : "false"` ⇒ `Boolean(0) ? "true" : "false"`. It happens to have a different result because it's a different type conversion, but it's still an implicit conversion.

Comment: answer to obvious question, it's different in different languages, because **they're different**, you can use [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to get boolean, if you want it so much, but it will also return true. I hope you understan why.

Answer (score 0):

Here  *Array()* is a constructor function that will point to a non-null, defined object even
  it would be empty in your example but a valid one and when it will be converted into
  boolean,it will be evaluated true (only *null* and *undefined* objects are evaluated to
  false).