# Why does an empty list evaluates to False on a while loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

What is process that occurs for a while-loop to evaluate to `False` on an empty list ?

For instance:

```
a=[1, 2, 3]
while a:
    a.pop()
```

Essentially, I want to know which method or attribute of the list object the `while`-loop is inspecting in order to decide wether to terminate or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty list is equal to None or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805882/empty-list-is-equal-to-none-or-not)

Comment: A better possible duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/q/10440792/8344060

Comment: @kvantour. Neither is a good duplicate

Comment: I agree with @Mad Physicist. I think the question here is much clearer, along with the solution provided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loops and conditionals implicitly use [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) on all their conditions. The procedure is documented explicitly in the ["Truth Value Testing"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) section of the docs. For a sequence like a list, this usually ends up being a check of the [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) method.

`bool` works like this: first it tries the [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method. If `__bool__` is not implemented, it checks if `__len__` is nonzero, and if that isn't possible, just returns `True`.

As with all magic method lookup, Python will only look at the class, never the instance (see [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup)). If your question is about how to change the behavior, you will need to subclass. Assigning a single replacement method to an instance dictionary won't work at all.

Comment: Is that true in Python 3+ ? I tried a=[]. Then a.__bool__() and it returns that this method does not exist.

Comment: @VanillaSpice. I've added to my answer

Comment: Actually, I found this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth, and will add it to your answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 4):

Great question! It's inspecting `bool(a)`, which (usually) calls `type(a).__bool__(a)`.

Python implements certain things using "magic methods". Basically, if you've got a data type defined like so:

```
class MyExampleDataType:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.val > 20
```

Then this code will do what it looks like it'll do:

```
a = MyExampleDataType(5)
b = MyExampleDataType(30)

if a:
    print("Won't print; 5 < 20")
if b:
    print("Will print; 30 > 20")
```

For more information, see the Python Documentation: [3.3 Special Method Names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

Comment: I tried mylist=[]. Then mylist.__bool__() and it returns that this method does not exist. Is the \_\_bool\_\_ method an actual method of list ?

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce It's complicated. Lists are a bad example; there isn't actually a `list.__bool__`. Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) for in-depth information; basically, Python's making up for the fact that `list.__bool__` isn't defined by figuring the information out another way (i.e., using `list.__len__`). There are hardly any special-cases like that, though (I think the `<=` comparison operators sometimes use stuff like `not >` if they're not defined explicitly, but I don't remember).

Comment: For backwards compatibility, the truthiness protocol has to keep considering the possibility that a class uses `__len__`, rather than the newcomer `__bool__` (or the Python 2 method `__nonzero__` it replaced), to define its truthiness. Since that was the case, there was no compelling reason to define `__bool__` *and* `__len__` for the built-in types like `list` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

A condition like `if my_var` is equivalent to `if bool(my_var)` and [this page](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bool) explains it rather nicely:

> Return Value from bool()
>
> The bool() returns:
>
> False if the value is omitted or false
> True if the value is true
>
> The following values are considered false in Python:
>
> None
>
> False
>
> Zero of any numeric type. For example, 0, 0.0, 0j
>
> Empty sequence. For example, (), [], ''.
>
> Empty mapping. For example, {}
>
> objects of Classes which has **bool**() or **len()** method which returns 0 or False
>
> All other values except these values are considered true.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a list is empty by using the bool() function. It evaluates to False if the variable doesn't exist or in the case of a list, when it is empty.

In your case you could do this:

```
a=[1,2,3]

while bool(a) is True:
    a.pop()
```

Or even easier:

```
a = [1,2,3]

while len(a) > 0:

    print(a.pop())
```