# while, for loop difference in the following Python codes

Tags: python

I'd like to know the difference between the following two codes using while and for loop in each.

I want to pop elements of the list `sandwich_orders` into the list of `finished_sandwich`. it seems to work with while loop but not with for loop. What mistake did I make?

```
sandwich_orders = ['chicken sandwich', 'beef sandwich', 'avocado sandwich', 'pork sandwich']
finished_sandwich = []

while sandwich_orders:
    cur_sandwich = sandwich_orders.pop()
    finished_sandwich.append(cur_sandwich)
print (finished_sandwich)

for cur_sandwich in sandwich_orders:
    cur_sandwich = sandwich_orders.pop()
    finished_sandwich.append(cur_sandwich)
print (finished_sandwich)
```

Comment: Please format your question properly. Indentation is critical in Python. Without a proper layout your code could be misinterpreted

Comment: You need to reinitialise `sandwich_orders` before your for loop. The list is empty after your while loop so the for loop never runs

Comment: sandwich_orders.pop() is emptying the sandwich_orders list

Comment: Even if the sandwich_orders list was populated prior to the *for* loop, the code makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve with the *for* loop?

Comment: check here an interesting question on while loops and lists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876593/why-does-an-empty-list-evaluates-to-false-on-a-while-loop-in-python

Comment: Never add or remove elements from a list while you're iterating over it with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The *for* loop could be written thus:

```
sandwich_orders = ['chicken sandwich', 'beef sandwich', 'avocado sandwich', 'pork sandwich']
finished_sandwich = []

for _ in sandwich_orders[:]:
  finished_sandwich.append(sandwich_orders.pop())
```

...or, to retain the order of the original list:

```
for _ in sandwich_orders[:]:
      finished_sandwich.insert(0, sandwich_orders.pop())
```

...or, to avoid loops altogether:

```
finished_sandwich = sandwich_orders[:]
```

Comment: you need to explain what : sandwich_orders[:] is

Comment: @pippo1980 Why do I need to explain that? It's been an inherent part of the language since Python2

Comment: cause I am a newbie like ullie and didnt see the finished_sandwich= [] mising in SAI answer and I need that to upvote your answer and there is no need for a deepcopy

Comment: Okey: if a is a list, a[:] returns a new object that is a copy of a:

Comment: if a is a list, a[:] returns a new object that is a copy of a:

```
>>> a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux', 'corge']
>>> a[:]
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux', 'corge']
>>> a[:] is a
False
```

While If s is a string, s[:] returns a reference to the same object:
```
>>> s = 'foobar'
>>> s[:]
'foobar'
>>> s[:] is s
True
```

Taken from [https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/

Answer (score 0):

After `while` loop, your variable `sandwich_orders` becomes empty as you are popping elements from it during the `while` loop. So you need to reinitialize it.Try in this way

```
sandwich_orders = ['chicken sandwich', 'beef sandwich', 'avocado sandwich', 'pork sandwich']
finished_sandwich = []

while sandwich_orders:
    cur_sandwich = sandwich_orders.pop()
    finished_sandwich.append(cur_sandwich)
print (finished_sandwich)

sandwich_orders = ['chicken sandwich', 'beef sandwich', 'avocado sandwich', 'pork sandwich']    
finished_sandwich= []

for cur_sandwich in sandwich_orders:
    finished_sandwich.append(cur_sandwich)
print (finished_sandwich)
```

Comment: But OP wants to *pop()* elements from sandwich_orders. Your *for* loop doesn't affect that list

Comment: I assumed he want to append elements from `sandwich_orders` to `finished_sandwich` using `while` and `for` loops.

Comment: I tried using `pop` for the `for` loop. But is popping every alternate element from the list

Comment: loop over a deepcopy of sandwich_orders (import copy, a = copy.deepcopy(sandwich_orders)) and pop from sandwich_orders

Comment: @pippo1980 There is no need for a deep copy